# Can't install Unity Tweak Tool - locale errors

Tags: unity, apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg

I am trying to install Unity Tweak Tool but I can't install it. I am getting the following output when I tried installing it via the Ubuntu Software Center

---

```
installArchives() failed: perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 197290 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../unity-tweak-tool_0.0.7-0~201~ubuntu15.10.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking unity-tweak-tool (0.0.7-0~201~ubuntu15.10.1) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/unity-tweak-tool_0.0.7-0~201~ubuntu15.10.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/share/unity-tweak-tool/monitor-window-snapping.png' to '/usr/share/unity-tweak-tool/monitor-window-snapping.png.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Error in function:
```

Answer (score -1):

Note that Unity Tweak Tool works on Ubuntu 12.10 and higher. If you want to install it on Ubuntu 12.10, you can use its PPA repository as follows. This PPA repository is also useful when you want to test the latest developments of the tool.

**You can use the following commands from your terminal**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

**Or you can also install it from your Software Center**

Comment: I m on Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: PS:- I got to installing the tweak tool but can seem to run it

Comment: I would say try to uninstall it and try again remember to update your system then reboot your  machine to complete.

Comment: The PPA `freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily` does not exist.